# Running a .py file before build in setup.py

Tags: python, build, easy-install

I'm creating a setup.py with easyinstall and I need to execute a certain py file in the same project before the build is done. I tried setup_requires and ext_modules, but both seem not to be able to call a python file in the same project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code creates a new build command that calls your own custom function before delegating to the original build command. In the following, `RunYourOtherScript()` stands for whatever you want to run before the `build` takes place. This could be a call to `execfile('src/something.py')` or preferably a relative import and a function call.

```
from distutils.command import build as build_module

class build(build_module.build):
  def run(self):
    RunYourOtherScript()
    build_module.build.run(self)

setup(
  ...
  cmdclass = {
      'build': build,
  },
)
```